# azure Virtual Machine IPv6 support

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ipv6

I have an IOS app connecting to my azure VM to retrieve data. It was working fine until recent app submission update, it was rejected due to not IPv6 supported. I tested my VM with this tool:

```
http://ready.chair6.net/
```

and it's indeed said that the connection to my server failed with IPv6 tests. It doesn't have AAAA record. Does Azure support IPv6 yet, I couldn't find anywhere in my portal to configure this.

Updated with Apple rejected reason

```
We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Next Steps

Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch without crashing.

Resources

For additional information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and Supporting IPv6-only Networks.

For a networking overview, please see About Networking.
```

Comment: That is not why your app was rejected. You need to read the message you received from Apple carefully. Then you need to carefully read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes I read it very carefully, my app don't use hard coded IPv4 style, and passed the test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility, but it was rejected 3 times. So for now Azure VM is the only reason I can think of.

Comment: More to the point: _we_ need to read the message you received from Apple.

Comment: The reason Apple gives is "as it crashed on launch".

Comment: Right. You're barking up the wrong tree here. You need to [symbolicate the crash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1460892/1068283) and debug it.

Comment: Just to reiterate Michael's comments, the Azure VM has nothing to do with your problem - the app crash is the problem, which may be that you're trying to do something specific with networking in your app that doesn't work.  Ive just put an iOS app through the app store that doesn't have anything specific to do with IPv6, and the back end is hosted on Azure (which doesn't support IPv6 yet).  Can you give some more detail on what's actually crashing in your app?

Comment: I have no idea what caused my app crash, I have tested everything in my development environment and ad hoc distribution, both are working fine. In fact the updated app I only did some minor changes which doesn't related to networking but it was rejected this time. Of course I investigated the crash log Apple provided but it doesn't help. I submitted a technical request to Apple to ask for their help, still waiting for their response.

Comment: I faced the same issue and it seems like our backend should support IPV6 addresses. Currently, we don't have AAAA entry in DNS record because we use Azure Web Sites and I haven't found anything in settings to turn-on IPV6 support.

Answer (score 0):

Azure support IPv6 now. (Only new Virtual Machines with Load balance.)

Apple **do not require** a server to have an IPv6 support.
Apple will use NAT64 to help user access IPv4 server for a IPv6 ONLY network.